# "Chair" or "chairman?"

Tags: word-choice

Is it right to use *chair*, but not *chairman* in this example?

> He served as the Department Chair from 1995 to 1999.

Comment: It's not really logical to call a person a chair. People don't normally talk to furniture, apart from Clint Eastwood last year.

Comment: Tristan: I suggest you look up the word _metonymy_ in any good dictionary.

Comment: Colin, you could always look up Clint Eastwood's chair incident from last year.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Traditionally the word *chairman* was used irrespective of whether the incumbent was a man or a woman. But over the last few decades many people have tried to avoid words which include the morpheme *man* because they are seen as excluding women.

Two of the solutions which have been applied to *chairman* are *chairperson* and *chair.* Both are now in wide use, probably *chair* more commonly.

There are a few people who object to either of these uses: probably the only way to express it that will not upset anybody is to avoid the noun altogether:

> He chaired the Department from 1995 to 1999

**Edit**

As jgbelacqua has pointed out, in the academic world the word *chair* existed as a post (professorship) long before the concerns I mentioned above. To refer to the holder of a chair as *the Chair* is simple metonymy, and well-established. This is different from outside academia, where *chair* did not exist in this sense, and so the use for a person came in as a neologism which some find awkward.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although I think that someone who is upset by the use of "chairman" to indicate a woman is not the best person to chair anything... sometimes I feel we're pushing the "politically correct" too far.

Comment: I agree. I think I will never be able to call a person chair.

Comment: I once saw a conference report which said "the floor withdrew its support from the chair and the platform" prompting ideas of physical collapse.  But, within reason, you should call people what they want to be called.

Comment: @nico PC is certainly being overdone these days... but, at least IMHO, this is not a case of too-much-PC.

Comment: @jae: I could agree, for chairperson. However, calling someone "chair" is simply silly.

Comment: I was thinking more of "chair" than "chairperson", but so tastes differ. ;-)

Comment: The term "Chair" as in "Department Chair" is not at all unusual, and has been standard in many academic departments for a long time.

Comment: "Con chair" (short for "convention chair") is common for science fiction conventions. Whether it makes etymological sense or not is irrelevant; it's an accepted usage. (As for talking to furniture, what about letters "from the desk of...")

Answer (score 5):

With regard to the question, it could be right to use *chair* or *chairperson*, or possibly both.  @Colin put it well -- you probably can't avoid upsetting someone unless you avoid the term altogether, but there will usually be a convention in place to guide you usage.

Nevertheless, there is plenty of precedent for *chair* by itself, so you need not feel as if you're bowing to some insidious and terrible force of political correctness.

If you regard the early 19th century as the start of the age of political correctness, it's possible that you will disagree.

To expand on my earlier comment ("The term *Chair* as in *Department Chair* is not at all unusual, and has been standard in many academic departments for a long time"), I thought I'd look at some historical usage of the term.

First, the metonymic use of *chair* to mean an authority is quite old.  The OED gives one of the definitions and earliest examples of this use as

> [3]. a. A seat of authority, state, or dignity; a throne, bench,
>   judgement-seat, etc.
>
> 1393    J.
>   Gower *Confessio* III. iv. 125   Ianus
>   with double face In his chare hath
>   take his place.
>   b. Place or situation of authority, etc.
>
> 1382    *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.) Matt.
>   xxiii. 2   Vpon the chaier of Moyses,
>   scribis and Pharisees seeten.

Bishops, episcopal authority:

> [4]. a. The seat of a bishop in his church;
>   hence fig. episcopal dignity or
>   authority. Obs. or arch.
>
> 1480    Caxton *Chron. Eng.* xl. 28
>   Seynt peter preched in antyoche and
>   ther he made a noble chirche in whiche
>   he sate fyrste in his chaier.
>
> 1591    *Troublesome Raigne Iohn* ii.
>   sig. E3,   Treads downe the Strumpets
>   pride, That sits vpon the chaire of
>   Babylon.

Here's a reference to professorship:

> [6]. a. The seat from which a professor or other authorized teacher delivers
>   his lectures.
>
> c1449    R. Pecock *Repressor* (1860)
>   518   To be rad‥in the chaier of
>   scolis.
>
> 1691    A. Wood *Athenæ Oxon*. II. 506
>   His prudent presiding in the
>   Professors chair.

Continuing --

> b. Hence: The office or position of a
>   professor.
>
> 1816    Scott *Antiquary*
>   III. ii. 39   Fighting his way to a
>   chair of rhetoric.
>
> 1856    R. W. Emerson *Eng. Traits* xii.
>   210   Many chairs and many fellowships
>   are made beds of ease.
>
> 1875    M. Arnold *Ess. Crit.* (ed. 3)
>   Pref. p. x (note)    The author had
>   still the Chair of Poetry at Oxford.
>
> [8]. The seat, and hence the office, of the chief magistrate of a corporate
>   town; mayorship. past, above, or below
>   the chair [[...]
>
> 1682    *Eng. Elect. Sheriffs* 26   Some
>   people‥did so industriously stickle
>   for Sir John Moor's Election to the
>   Chair.
>
> 1714    *London Gaz.* No. 5261/4,   The
>   Aldermen below the Chair on Horseback
>   in Scarlet Gowns.

Presiding Chairs!

> [9]. a. The seat occupied by the
>   person presiding at a meeting, from
>   whence he directs its business; hence,
>   the office or dignity of chairman of a
>   meeting, or of the Speaker of the
>   House of Commons.
>
> <sup>In various phrases,
>   as to take the chair, to assume the
>   position of chairman, which in most
>   cases formally opens a meeting; to put
>   in the chair, to elect as chairman; in
>   the chair, acting as chairman; to
>   leave or vacate the chair, to cease
>   acting as chairman, which marks the
>   close of a meeting.</sup>
>
> 1659    T. Burton *Diary* (1828) IV.
>   462,   I move that your Speaker
>   forbear the Chair.
>
> 1702    *Clarendon's Hist. Rebellion* I.
>   iv. 233   The Committee of the Commons
>   appointed Mr Pym to sit in the Chair.

*Chair! Chair!*

> b. Often put for the occupant of the
>   chair, the chairman, as invested with
>   its dignity [...], e.g. in the cry
>   Chair! Chair! when the authority of
>   the chairman is appealed to, or not
>   duly regarded; to address the chair,
>   support the chair, etc. Now also used
>   as an alternative for ‘chairman’ or
>   ‘chairwoman’, esp. deliberately so as
>   not to imply a particular sex.
>
> 1658–9    T. Burton *Diary* 23 Mar.
>   (1828) 243   The Chair behaves himself
>   like a Busby amongst so many
>   school-boys‥and takes a little too
>   much on him.

Other examples of metonymy which superficially resemble referring to people as objects :  the crown, the board, the bar, the panel, the suits, the big guns, etc..

Comment: You will not call the Queen "Her Majesty Crown", will you? But thanks for the answer, it was interesting to read it.

Comment: @Edwin Ross - no, but you talk about the Crown doing something or of something being owned by the Crown.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that you have to call a certain person "chair" even when addressing him and not the authority or symbol that he represents.

Comment: @Edwin -- see the last definition, (b) for that usage (present since at least 1828).

Comment: Thank you jgbelacqua, I understand that I will have to get used to it somehow.

Comment: @Edwin There are always words and ways of using them that can annoy us, I think.  This one doesn't bother me, but others will, no doubt.

Comment: @jbelacqua The large majority of your quotes actually refer to the chair in which the chairperson sits and/or to the authority of the chairperson - they do NOT refer to the person as 'Chair'. e.g. *The seat occupied by the person presiding*; *the office or dignity of chairman*; *to take the chair; to assume the position of chairman*; *the cry Chair! Chair! when the authority of the chairman*; etc.. Several of those quotes actually refer to both *chair* and *chairman*, thus distinguishing between the two. They do NOT refer to the person as *chair*.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, in your example

> He served as the Department Chair from 1995 to 1999.

*chair* is correct. *Department Chair* is a well-established idiomatic phrase, especially in academic circles in the United States. (You might find *HODs* elsewhere.) You could also say *Chairman of the Department* in a non-academic context.

Answer (score 3):

From a purely logical, accurate description, in the interest of communicating reality:

Chairman is a man; Chairwoman is a woman;  Chairperson would be acceptable for either.

Keep it simple silly!

Comment: I agree! If we use *chair* for *chairperson*, do we use *spokes* for a *spokesman/spokesperson*, or *work* for a *workman*, or *post* for a *postman* (same as "mailman" in the US I think), and so on?!

Comment: Jennifer, that's a good point and the most logical answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

### [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/man?q=man)

> Definition of **man**
>   *noun*  (plural ***men***)
>   1. ...
>   2. a human being of either sex; a person: *God cares for all men*
>     (also **Man**) [*in singular*] human beings in general; the human race: *places untouched by the ravages of man*

### [Chambers](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/)

> **man** *noun* (***men***)
>   ...
>   6.: human being; a person
>   - *the right man for the job
>
>   - Time waits for no man
>
>   - manhunt
>
>   - man-made
>
>   - a two-man job*.

Like it or not, ***man*** is an accepted English term for a 'generic' person.

Yes, if it bothers people, it's easy enough to substitute 'person' or 'woman' in many instances.

### [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chair?q=chair)

> Definition of **chair**
>   *noun* 
>   1. a separate seat for one person, typically with a back and four legs. ...
>   2. the person in charge of a meeting or of an organization (used as a neutral alternative to chairman or chairwoman): *she’s the chair of a research committee*
>   - the post of a chairperson: *he was due to step down after a three-year stint in the chair*
>   3. a professorship: *he held a chair in physics*
>   4. ...
>   *verb [with object]*
>   1. act as chairperson of or preside over (an organization, meeting, or public event): 
>   *the debate was chaired by the Archbishop of York*
>   2. ...

### [Chambers](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/)

> **chair**
>   ***noun***
>   1. a seat for one person, with a back-support and usually four legs.
>   2. the office of chairman or chairwoman at a meeting, etc, or the person holding this office.
>   3. a professorship.
>   4. ...
>   ***verb*** (***chaired, chairing***)
>   1. to control or conduct (a meeting) as chairman or chairwoman.
>   2. ...
>   3. to place someone in a seat of authority.
>   **in the chair** acting as chairman.
>   **take the chair** to be chairman or chairwoman.
>   **ETYMOLOGY**: 13: from French *chaiere*, from Latin *cathedra*, from Greek *kathedra* seat.

Yes, ***chair*** is now included in authoritative dictionaries as a term for the person chairing a meeting, etc. (as well as for the name of the office or authority), but personally, I still feel as if I would be talking to a piece of furniture if I were to address the chairperson as "chair"!

Answer (score 1):

Largely as a consequence of having evolved from so many different linguistic roots, English is unrivalled in its elasticity and its capacity for further evolution. This can be a good thing or a bad thing, depending on where you choose to be in the spectrum of tolerating change. The effect of this flexibility is that a word or term, used widely and frequently enough and over a period of time, can become acceptable, even if its origin is in ignorance.  The term 'Chair' is (or, one might argue, should be) more commonly applied to an office than it is to a person. Some of the metonymic examples cited on this page, whilst instructive, are not particularly helpful. 'He held the chair of the department' would be stylistically preferable to 'he was the chair of the department'; that is, as long as the context allows one to avoid the misunderstanding that the subject was either an animated piece of furniture, a furniture removal man, or somebody involved in an amorous embrace with a senior academic. If the debate is about political correctness, one should take care to avoid assuming that a word ending in -man *necessarily* denotes the masculine. There are plenty of lady chairmen of corporations. Or is that woman chairmen? Or should that be woperson?

To answer the question: unless it's a specific reference to academia, the words 'Chair' and 'Chairman' would be interchangeable in the example given, but 'Chairman' would be better.

Comment: Hello again, Philanthropistrog. This is great stuff. Just fyi, we very much appreciate links to sources which support answers (not expected in comments). Thanks so much. :-)